# Qual è il significato di "spazzolato" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto questa frase:

> Ivan si alzò dal tronco e appoggiando le mani sul sedere si accorse che il fondo dei calzoni piú che **spazzolato**
>   andava strizzato.

Secondo i dizionari, "spazzolare" significa pulire o sistemare con la spazzola oppure, in senso figurato, mangiare voracemente o con avidità. Tuttavia, non capisco cosa possa significare un fondo di calzoni "spazzolato" nella frase precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per pulire i vestiti si usano delle spazzole speciali, morbide, che consentono di togliere polvere o piccoli residui dalla stoffa. Si possono pulire i pantaloni anche con le mani. Se mi capita di stare seduta su un prato o sulla spiaggia, quando mi rialzo il primo gesto è quello di passare le mani sulle gambe, sui pantaloni, per "pulirli". Così fa Ivan, dopo essere stato seduto sul tronco, per togliere piccoli pezzi di corteccia. Ma il tronco è bagnato (piove molto in quei giorni), quindi i pantaloni non si sono sporcati ma bagnati, vanno quindi strizzati e non spazzolati.